# Adding product to wishlist at catalog page

Tags: addtowishlist

When I am trying to add product to wishlist at catalog page, it only reloads page and nothing else happens. At product page it works.

Comment: Please provide more details about your Magento version and customization like theme, etc

Comment: Hello Victor. I work with Magento 2.